# Django Rest Framework deserialize queryset into other model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a generic 'Order' model. There are other models which represent other forms of 'Order's.

I need to deserialize these other instance to our generic 'Order' model. So I retrieve a queryset and turn it into a list but am unable to correctly deserialize it into Order.

Order has 4 fields, reference, delivery_date, note and customer_note.
The other model has equivalent fields named external_reference, requested_delivery_date, note and customer_note.

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reference = serializers.CharField(source='external_reference', required=True)
    delivery_date = serializers.DateField(source='requested_delivery_date')
    note = serializers.CharField()
    customer_note = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('reference',
              'delivery_date',
              'note',
              'customer_note')
```

Since you can't provide a QuerySet as data input for a Serializer I turned it into a list:

```
orders = AppOrder.objects.all()
data = list(orders.values())
serialized = OrderSerializer(data=data, many=True)
```

However, this does not work. Source does not grab the correct field:

> delivery_date': ['This field is required.']

It may be that I am doing this entirely wrong and that there are better ways to deserialize one model to another, if so please do tell as well.

Edit: (added 31 oct)

The situation we have is that there are multiple possible implementations of an 'Order'. We have X which has a DB with an Order table. You also have Y with another Order table. We use non-managed models to retrieve data from those. We got an API endpoint to return order information. This endpoint uses the Order model which we made ourself. When a call is made to the endpoint we check who is making the request, go to the correct non-managed model and fetch the orders. The problem is that these are other models, in this case AppOrder(s). So it returns a QuerySet of AppOrders. Since the endpoint expects an Order QuerySet I need to turn AppOrders to a Order QuerySet so that I can display it/filter it/order it/etc, hence why I try to serialize AppOrder into Order.

Answer (score 0):

```
delivery_date = serializers.DateField(source='requested_delivery_date', required=False)
```

This might work.